# How to prevent fstab errors from bricking Raspberry pi 400?

Tags: pi-400

I'm trying to set something up on a Raspberry PI 400 with an external USB drive, and every time I make the slightest mistake in fstab I have to start again from scratch. It just boots to emergency mode as described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/t6795f/emergency_mode_with_root_account_locked/

This happens even if the external drive is temporarily unavailable, rather than just booting up without the drive. Bricking the device so readily is obviously unacceptable. On other linuxes it sounds like you can just select something in GRUB, but the pi doesn't have that. How can I make it possible to edit fstab when booting fails, on the pi itself?

Comment: I expect them to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Bricking the device so readily is obviously unacceptable.

The system is **not bricked**.  Bricked means beyond repair -- as you said, "start again from scratch".

Creating a problem with a typo, etc., in `/etc/fstab` is not beyond repair and does not require you start again from scratch.  What it requires you do is put the SD card in another machine and fix `/etc/fstab`, which is in the second partition for most Rpi installs including the standard official RpiOS.

Doing that with a laptop, etc., is much more of a PITA since, if it were not for the options provided by grub, or re-mouting the fs rw from the emergency shell, etc., would require you take the drive out to perform the fix, or, if the BIOS allows you to choose a different boot medium (which they normally do) you can (eg.) use a system on a USB stick to do it.

Fortunately, this is not a significant issue on the Pi so the lack of bootloader features and stupidly hamstrung by default root account does not matter.

The only roadblock here would be if you do not have a system that can read from and write to the ext4 partition the SD card, in which case if you at least have another computer with a USB or SD card slot can be arranged with software.<sup>1</sup>  If not, *the problem is not that the system is bricked, it is that you do not have the proper tools to deal with the problem* -- but these tools are easily acquired at no expense and require little skill to use.

> This happens even if the external drive is temporarily unavailable...

You should try adding `nofail` to the mount options (4th field) in fstab, see `man fstab`.

---

1. Eg. If all you have is a Windows box you can use a virtual machine running linux or some other OS that can access ext4 filesystems.